# NGINX if condition have and condition

Tags: if-statement, nginx, conditional-statements

i want to make a condition if it fulfills
abc.com/abc.m3u8?token=abcd
if conditions are met then allow
otherwise return 403
I'm a little confused because I can't use nested if in nginx

`

```
     if ($uri !~* "^(.*)/(abc.m3u8)(.*)" && $arg_token !~* "abcd"){
        return 403;
}
```

`

Comment: after request abc.m3u8
then the browser will request again
abc.com/1.ts
abc.com/2.ts
where 1.ts must allow, the if condition above will block abc.com/1.ts
how to handle 1.ts requests too?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request_uri` to check if the URL matches `abc.com/abc.m3u8?token=abcd` :

```
if ($request_uri !~* "^/abc\.m3u8\?token=abcd$") {
  # Return a 403 Forbidden status if the URL does not match the pattern
  return 403;
}
```

Comment: sorry, there is a need for additional
because the m3u8 live video will have more requests asking
abc.com/1.ts
abc.com/2.ts
where if set if statement above, request 1.ts will get response 403